# Getting Error Message from Tomcat error page with Angular 7

Tags: java, angular, tomcat

I'm using `response.sendError(400,"MyErrorMessage");` in Java to send and error response to the client. My Client is an Angular app and I would like to be able to get this messages in it so I could display it in a toast.

The problem is i'm using Tomcat and it returns an ugly error page, and I don't get how to get my error message from it. Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you add your java and angular code, so that we can understand better what is happening?

Comment: Which kind of Java framework are you using? SpringBoot?

Comment: No it's pure Java EE with HttpServlets

Comment: In fact when i send an error response in Java, it's intercepted by my Tomcat Server. As the response code provided is known as an error code in Tomcat, Tomcat send back an error page to the client. The page looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ1l2.png.

I would like to be able to get only the message part of this response to be able to display it in a toast in my Angular client.